# Import data from existing word document to new one automatically

Tags: microsoft-word, vba, macros

all,

I would like to import data from an existing word document into a new word document automatically based on stored values inside variables.
Eg. var 1 - text 1, var 2 - text 2 etc
I want this variables that have stored text inside to be at one click away (multiple choice boxes)
I've done my research and all I could find is how to import from word to excel, yet I need em to be from word to word.
I'm leaving here what I have already found:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16919535/importing-specific-data-from-a-word-to-excel
Any hints would be of great help.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

### Word has built in functions for what is known as "boiler plate." AutoText and Building Blocks.

See my page on these: [Automated Boiler Plate in Word](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/autotextautocorrect.htm).

You can use the AutoTextList field and / or Building Blocks Gallery Content Control to easily choose and insert snippets of text into your document. Here is a [sample template](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lhhdf6svv19nyqc/Building%20Blocks%20Gallery%20Content%20Control%20and%20AutoTextList%20Fields%20Compared.zip?dl=0) I've prepared comparing these. Either can let you insert pages of information if you have saved it as AutoText or a Building Block.

- Here is my writing on the [Building Blocks Gallery Content Control](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/autotextautocorrect.htm#BBGalleryContentControl).
  [image: Screenshot of Building Blocks Gallery Content Control in action]
- Here are two articles on the AutoTextList field:

  [AutoTextList in the Modern Age](https://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/autotextlist_in_the_modern_age.html) by Greg Maxey

  [How to add pop-up lists to any Word document so you can click your way through changes in seconds](http://word.mvps.org/FAQs/TblsFldsFms/AutoTextList.htm) by Bill Coan.

  [image: Screenshot of AutoTextList Field in action]